# How to pass byte array from android java class to JNI C NDK?

Tags: android

I have byte array in java class , and i want to pass that byte array to JNI C class, I am not able to access that array in JNI C, please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you need to declare the JNI function that receives the array like this (in Java):

> private native void sendData(byte[] data);

you call the function like any other function:

> sendData(buffer);

and then in your C code implement the function like this:

> JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_packageXXX_yourClass_sendData( JNIEnv*
>   env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray data);

read the array:

> byte * cData = env->GetByteArrayElements(data, &isCopy);

and release:

> env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, cData, JNI_ABORT);

the above code is C++. To make it work for C you need to pass the jni environement (env) as the first parameter of the function you are calling, like this:

> (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,...)

Comment: Thanks for great answer, But i have one problem, Method 'GetByteArrayElements' could not be resolved,,, how to remove this error???? its always shown to me when i try to use env methods??

Comment: env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, cData, JNI_ABORT); also could not resolved

Comment: if you are using plain C then you need (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, isCopy). Check out this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: i get the reference of this method in jni.h , but although "GetByteArrayElements" error is showing

Comment: right now I have this in my code and it works perfectly: short * cData = (short*)env->GetShortArrayElements(data, &isCopy); Looking at the functions listed in the link above, GetByteArrayElements() is also available. Are you sure that the array passed to the function is a jbyteArray? Are you writing C or C++ code?

Comment: jboolean isCopy;
 rgba8888* surface_buffer = (rgba8888 *) malloc(4);
 jbyte * cData = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, &isCopy);
 jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, buffer);

Comment: im doing like above, and error comes : Method 'GetByteArrayElements' could not be resolved

Comment: all the likes this, (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, buffer); shows error to me methods could not be resolved