# undefined reference to 'multiply' using JNI in android

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am new in android `JNI` and trying below code:

**Package Name :** `com.example.jnitest`

**Java class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();


    System.out.println("Sum of two variables : "+ sumOfTwovariable((int)mainActivity.multiply(10, 25), 10));
}

public native long sumOfTwovariable(int v1, int v2);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("JNITest");
}

public native long multiply(int v1, int v2);
static{
    System.loadLibrary("com_example_pdemo_MainActivity");
}

}
```

---

**Android.mk file**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := JNITest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JNITest.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := Prebuild_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Prebuild_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Prebuild_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=    $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcom_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**I have prebuild com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so lib placed inside JNI-> armeabi(write multiple function) folder include in Android.mk file**

---

Inside JNI :

Create the header file using : javah -jni -classpath....

```
Header file created using javah : com_example_jnitest_MainActivity.h

  /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_jnitest_MainActivity */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity
#define _Included_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_jnitest_MainActivity
  * Method:    sumOfTwovariable
  * Signature: (II)J
*/
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL    Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_sumOfTwovariable(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

### #endif

Defination of the native function :JNITest.cpp

```
  #include "com_example_jnitest_MainActivity.h"

extern "C" {
long multiply(int val1,int val2);
}

   JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL      Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_sumOfTwovariable(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint val1, jint val2) {
int val=multiply(val1,val2);
return (val+val1);
```

}

**When i compile it, i got undefined reference to 'multiply'.Let me know what mistake i have done.**

**Thanks in Advance..**

Comment: have you defined multiply anywhere in your native code?

Comment: Yes I have.  I have written multiple function definition inside the com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so(exteranl .so file).

Comment: @YogeshChander Where did you define multiply?

Comment: I have written multiply function definition inside the com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so (prebuilt shared library file).

Comment: post your native code for com_example_pdemo please

Comment: #include "com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.h"
    #include <errno.h>
    long multiply(int val1,int val2)
    {
           return val1*val2;
    }
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity_multiply
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint v1, jint v2){
     return  multiply(v1, v2);
    }

Comment: is that a C file or a C++ file?

Comment: if it's a C++ file, then remove the extern "C" from around the declaration of multiply() in JNITest.cpp

Comment: please find the source code at path :  https://drive.google.com/a/omnipayments.com/file/d/0B5D_FogJmZc-c0N3VEF3dDZjaVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside your native code for com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so, define multiply like this:

```
// this can be called from native code, including in different .so files:
long multiply(int val1,int val2)
{
    long result;
    // ...compute result...
    return result;
}

// this can be called from Java via JNI:
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity_multiply(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint a, jint b)
{
     return multiply(a, b);
}
```

This will allow you to call it from native code or via JNI.

Change your Android.mk file to this, putting the prebuilt .so file first:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Prebuild_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=    $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcom_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := JNITest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JNITest.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := Prebuild_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Lastly, inside your Java code, load both libraries inside a single static block, in this order:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("com_example_pdemo_MainActivity");
    System.loadLibrary("JNITest");
}
```

JNITest needs com_example_pdemo_MainActivity so it needs to go first or you'll get a runtime link error.

Also, in JNITest.cpp, remove the `extern "C"` surrounding the declaration of multiply(). If you have compiled your com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so file with C++ linkage then using a C extern will cause a link error when trying to link with JNITest:

```
// extern "C"{ <-- remove
    long multiply(int v1,int v2);
//} <-- remove
```

How to pass data to and from JNI in byte buffers:

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_compressImage(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject this, jobject inputByteBuffer, jobject outputByteBuffer)
{
    jbyte* pInBuf = (jbyte*)(*pEnv)->GetDirectBufferAddress(pEnv, inputByteBuffer);
    jbyte* pOutBuf = (jbyte*)(*pEnv)->GetDirectBufferAddress(pEnv, outputByteBuffer);

    int lenOutImage = 0; char *pOutputImage;
    pOutputImage = CompressImage((char *)pInBuf,&lenOutImage);

    // copy to byte buffer
    memcpy((char)pOutBuf, pOutputImage, lenOutImage);        
    free(pOutputImage); // free pOutputImage?

    return lenOutImage;
}
```

Comment: Why? Why write two methods where one will do?

Comment: @EJP Because OP wants to call multiply() from native code and also from Java (given that there is a native declaration). it's possible to call Java_com_example_pdemo_MainActivity_multiply directly from Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_sumOfTwovariable, pointlessly passing the env and obj parameters but that's rather ugly isn't? Do they have to use the JNI version every time they want to call it from within native code?

Comment: There isn't a single word in his question about callng `multiply()`  from native code.

Comment: @EJP yes there is. that's what he's attempting to do in JNITest.cpp and that's what's causing the error

Comment: i have tried it but got same issue.Let me know any other suggestion for the same.Thanks

Comment: are you sure the error is happening when compiling and not when linking?

Comment: So his JNITest.cpp is also wrong. It should be written in Java for a start.

Comment: @EJP well if OP just wants to multiply a couple of numbers together then obviously he could write the whole thing in Java. But I assume the point of this question is to present an MCVE of calling a JNI-exported native function in one .so file from a JNI-exported native function in another .so file

Comment: Is it possible i can share my whole project for better understanding.

Comment: Please find the source code at path : https://drive.google.com/a/omnipayments.com/file/d/0B5D_FogJmZc-c0N3VEF3dDZjaVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @samgak and EJP for your help on this. This did the trick and is working now - life saver!!! I have one more doubt. Actually there is a C Function which uses the following parameters int CompressImage (char *InputImage, char *OutputImage); What this function does is, takes input image as Input and returns the Compressed form of the image and the length of the same. How can I call this from my Java Code? I cannot pass pointers from Java hence I am struggling with this basic thing. CompressedImage is in an external .so library.

Comment: is the input image a file path or the actual image data. if it's image data, then pass it to JNI in a byte buffer. you can pass a second byte buffer in the same call to receive the compressed data. will update answer with basic skeleton

Comment: Sorry, please read as below:
int lenOutImage = 0;
char *OutputImage;
OutputImage = CompressImage((char *)InputImage,&lenOutImage);

Comment: see updates. you will need to allocate enough space in your output bytebuffer to hold the compressed image. also add error checking etc. If you have problems please open a new question

Comment: @samgak, i am capturing the image as BYTE array in Java. And now need to invoke the C native method as defined above.

Comment: you can convert a byte array to a bytebuffer. or just pass a byte array instead. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649808/how-to-pass-byte-array-from-android-java-class-to-jni-c-ndk

Comment: I have posted a new question for this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138195/passing-image-data-from-java-to-c-native-function-accepting-pointers

Answer (score 0):

multiply is also native method. It should be defined as same as sumOfTwovariable:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL    Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_multiply(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);
```

Comment: I have prebuild shared library com_example_pdemo_MainActivity.so lib placed inside JNI-> armeabi.In that prebuild shared library, i have define the multiply function

Comment: @YogeshChander But have you defined it ***as per the code in this question?***