# Passing Image Data from Java to C Native function accepting pointers

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, function-pointers

I have been provided a C function in an external .so file. This function takes Image data as input and provides the compressed image along with lengh of the image as output.

The function template is as follows:

char *OutputImage = CompressImage((char *)InputImage, (int)&lenOutImage);

In my Java code, I capture the input image as byte[] data type. Now I need to pass this to native C function mentioned above. Can you please help how I can achieve this from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, use JNI, or JNA. Discussing how to do that in detail is to big for this platform.

Comment: I understand, but can you share a sample Java declaration as to how to invoke this C function and pass String/Byte as pointer?