# convert byte [] to Mat

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, dji-sdk

I am trying to pass frame from DJI Phantom video live feed in java to native c++ in android studio and then convert it to Mat to apply opencv filters.

**JAVA SIDE**

```
mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new VideoFeeder.VideoDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
            if (mCodecManager != null) {
                mCodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
            }
        }
    };
```

in this part videoBuffer is byte [] type. i want to pass it to native c++ then convert it to Mat so that i can apply opencv filters.

Any idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the byte [] to C++ or how to convert it to Mat in C++? For the former question, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649808/how-to-pass-byte-array-from-android-java-class-to-jni-c-ndk) and for the latter question, take a look at [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/33596/convert-mat-to-byte-in-c/)

Comment: i have passed byte [] videoBuffer to JNI C class as jbyteArray and know i am trying to convert this jbyteArray into Mat in C class.

Comment: i am getting use of undeclared identifier error at &isCopy which is under jbyte * cData = (jbyte*)env->GetShortArrayElements(byteArray,&isCopy);

Comment: What you are asking is mentioned in the links that I have posted in the comments.